# Cannot resolve hostname (updating hostname for machine on local LAN) when attempting to contact a Raspberry Pi via hostname

Tags: linux, ssh, lan, hostname

I have connected a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04 to my local LAN over Wi-Fi.

From my laptop I can SSH to the Raspberry Pi just fine with:

```
$ ssh ubuntu@192.168.0.47
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1022-raspi aarch64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
 ...
```

Instead of having to type that IP each time I would like to be able to SSH to it using the hostname: `rasp01`. I have found this guide:

https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/19668676-renaming-your-raspberry-pi-the-hostname

That I have followed. After I have rebooted the Raspberry Pi and logged into it I have this:

```
ubuntu@rasp01:~$ hostname
rasp01

ubuntu@rasp01:~$ cat /etc/hosts

rasp01 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

ubuntu@rasp01:~$ cat /etc/hostname 
rasp01
```

But when I try to use that hostname when I SSH to the Raspberry Pi from my laptop on the same LAN (also running Ubuntu) I get:

```
$ ssh ubuntu@rasp01
ssh: Could not resolve hostname rasp01: Name or service not known

$ ssh ubuntu@rasp01.local
ssh: Could not resolve hostname rasp01.local: Name or service not known

$ ssh ubuntu@rasp01.local.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname rasp01.local.: Name or service not known
```

What am I missing?

It’s fine if I have to suffix it with `*.local` but that does not seem to work. Related thread here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/7q6mih/why_can_i_ping_with_ip_but_not_with_hostname/dso1cc4/

Where the user apparently got it to work with `*.local` eventually.

Also, the Raspberry Pi 4 will be part of a Raspberry Picluster where I will install docker/kubernetes (lab fun). My experience is that networking already becomes quite more complex when adding just Docker to the mix also confirmed by this article:

https://gnanesh.me/avahi-docker-non-root.html

Seen from this perspective would it be "simpler" to install my own internal DNS:

https://medium.com/nuculabs/setting-up-a-simple-dns-server-859de750f6fe

server instead of [installing Avahi on the nodes as suggested in an answer below](https://superuser.com/a/1609217/167207)?

Comment: just add the hostname and IP into your local hosts file.

Comment: But what if the IP changes?

Comment: Search this website for "mdns", "avahi-daemon", or "LLMNR"

Comment: I assume you have a router with DHCP, most of them have a a DHCP reservation option so you can fix the IP, or if you have a range for DHCP you can set a static one on your rasp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Just install `avahi-daemon` on the Raspberry Pi.

The [`avahi-daemon`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/avahi-daemon)basically sets a multicast hostname on the Raspberry Pi that *should* be broadcast across your LAN:

> “The Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD daemon implements Apple’s Zeroconf architecture (also known as ‘Rendezvous’ or ‘Bonjour’). The daemon registers local IP addresses and static services using mDNS/DNS-SD and provides two IPC APIs for local programs to make use of the mDNS record cache the avahi-daemon maintains.”

Installing it is quite simple:

```
sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon avahi-utils;
```

And that should be that! Then whatever the hostname of that device is can be reaching on your network at `[hostname].local`. Just ping it from another device on your network like this:

```
ping rasp01.local
```

And you should see it resolve to that device’s IP address. If you don’t see it show up immediately, wait a minute or so and ping again. And perhaps restart the Avahi service like this:

```
sudo service avahi-daemon restart
```

And you should be good.

In general, editing a Hosts file (`/etc/hosts/`) is a horribly kludgey way of doing this. It requires manual intervention and if the IP address changes, guess what? More manual intervention. Avahi is the way to go.

Comment: Great this seems like the way to go. I have added an update to my question since there is a bit more complexity coming to my setup and I was wondering if setting up an internal dedicated DNS server would actually be better (see updated question)?

Comment: @u123 Avahi is simpler. You literally just have to install Avahi on each node and it just will automatically establish a `[node].local` hostname that is broadcast on the network. In contrast a dedicated DNS server would not only require you to setup that DNS server but also *manually* set records for *each* node in the cluster. The only place Avahi is *not* recommended is if you were creating nodes in the real world. Avahi is mainly for LANs and DNS servers are mainly for larger Internet infrastructure. For a Raspberry Pi cluster on a LAN? Avahi all the way.

Comment: Ok actually I don't mind the extra hazzle since this is a homelab/learning project. Eventually I will also like to test that I can connect to the cluster from the internet, will running Avahi on my local LAN conflict with this use case?

Comment: @u123 I answered your question as you stated and presented: “I have connected a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04 to my local LAN over Wi-Fi.” The Avahi method is what it is as I have explained that it will solve the issues you are facing on your LAN. The DNS mthod is what it is. If you have a new question, you need to post a new question. I cannot help you further. You need to use what you need to use. If you feel thus answer has helped you, please be sure to upvote it. If it is the answer that solved your problem, please be sure to check it off as such. Best of luck in your endeavors!

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing?

IP LANs do not have a universal method for local hostname lookup – there *are* several protocols but they're more like add-ons. Often they need to be manually enabled, especially on Linux.

Usually your home router will provide **internal DNS.** If the Pi uses DHCP, it will advertise its hostname when sending the DHCP lease request – most home routers will then publish it in a local DNS domain (e.g. `.home` or `.lan` or something equally made-up).

Corporate networks and custom DHCP servers usually won't have such automatic registration.

Note that this method doesn't work with static IP addresses (use a DHCP reservation if you want that) and it doesn't automatically detect hostname changes. So if you *just now* renamed the Pi, you must **restart its DHCP client** and have it get a new lease.

It also requires other computers to know the DNS search suffix that your router's DNS uses. This too is automatically retrieved from the router via DHCP but must be manually configured if the host uses a static address.

The other option is **Multicast DNS (mDNS)**. This is the one that uses `.local`. To make this work on Linux you need to install **avahi-daemon** and **libnss-mdns** on all devices that will participate.

mDNS is also a standard part of macOS and available for Windows 10 through a Registry change.

As the name implies, mDNS uses multicast packets – those aren't always reliable over WiFi, and some wireless networks block them outright. Make sure your router doesn't.

LLMNR is very similar to mDNS, but doesn't use any domain suffix. It is primarily used by Windows but also supported by systemd-resolved on Linux. You can run both if you want.

(There's also NetBIOS, the one that Windows used to use in the past. Was once very common (though unreliable), but now rare with the removal of SMBv1. Samba supports it but don't bother.)

> But what if the IP changes

Most routers have the ability to permanently assign DHCP leases to specific devices. (This might be called "static lease" or "reservation" but it doesn't always have a specific name.) If you want the Pi to always be 192.168.3.14 or whatever, it can be done.

Comment: what do you mean with "Corporate networks and custom DHCP servers usually won't have such automatic registration."??? - [see this Microsoft article about DNS and DHCP registration](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51810.windows-server-integration-between-dns-and-dhcp.aspx) that is exactly how a Microsoft Corporate network is most often setup.